# reading in CSV with D3 js

Tags: javascript, csv, d3.js

I think this is probably a simple question so apologies in advance if this is silly.

I'm trying to figure out how to read in data from a .csv file with D3. Why is it that my variable "dataset" prints to the console within the function, but no longer displays afterwards?

```
var dataset;

d3.text("https://googledrive.com/host/0B2OWv79OnxJSczZRaTF2N1BuaVE", function(datasetText) {

    var parsedData = d3.csv.parseRows(datasetText);
    dataset = parsedData;
    console.log(dataset);
});

console.log(dataset);
```

Does this mean I have to write all of my relevant code in this d3.text() block? Additionally, what does putting code in this d3.text() actually do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to answer the third question you asked first.

> > what does putting code in this `d3.text()` actually do?

`d3.text` can be passed an optional callback function that according to [the docs](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Requests#d3_text), is called with two arguments -- "the error, if any, and the response text" -- after the text file is loaded. Thus if you want to process the file you are loading with `d3.text`, a simple way is to pass `d3.text` a callback function that will do the processing for you (as you started to do in your example).

---

Back to your first question.

> > Why is it that my variable "dataset" prints to the console within the function, but no longer displays afterwards?

The reason that `dataset` only has a value in the callback function passed to `d3.text` is because the text file is being loaded asynchronously. This means that the flow of the program does not stop and wait for `d3.text` to finish loading your text file, but continues to execute. Thus, `dataset` is first logged as having no value from the last line of your example, and is later logged in your `d3.text` callback function *after* being loaded.

---

Finally, your second question.

> > Does this mean I have to write all of my relevant code in this `d3.text()` block?

While you do not have to put all your relevant code in the callback passed to `d3.text` (e.g. you could use [jQuery's `Promise`](http://api.jquery.com/promise/)), this is a pretty common way to write D3 code (and Javascript code in general). One way to make your code cleaner is to organize it as follows:

```
d3.text("file-name", createChart);
function createChart(datasetText){
    ...
}
```

Here you are defining the callback function `createChart` in a different place from where you load the data, which at times makes your code easier to read and use.

Comment: Ah, I never realized that asynchronous loading could be so confusing, thank you

Comment: I had one more question, if you wouldn't mind considering it. What do I do in the case that I have more than one .csv file's data that I need to access at once?

Comment: @Null-Username: probably the simplest answer is to nest the requests e.g. `d3.csv("file1", function(data1){ d3.csv("file2", function(data2){ createChart(data1, data2) }) })`.

Comment: I got my code to work when I replaced `d3.csv` with `d3.text` and added the `"text/csv"` parameter: `d3.text("file1", "text/csv", function(data1){d3.text("file2", "text/csv", function(data2){parseData(data1, data2);}) });`

What is the difference between the two, and why do I get `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function` when I try using d3.csv? 

And again, thank you so much for your clear, helpful, and prompt answers!